# Mysql replace column value with other column value

Tags: mysql, replace, coalesce

I have 2 tables:

```
table: transaction:
====================
id  billed_date   amount
 1  2016-09-30      5
 2  2016-10-04      15
 3  2016-10-06      10

table: report_date
====================
transaction_id    report_date
      1            2016-10-01
```

**I want:**

- Create a report which sum all transactions's amount in October 2016
- Base on report date, not billed date
- When report date is not set, it's base on billed_date
- In above example, I want result is 30 (not 25)

**Then I write:**

The First:

```
SELECT 
   sum(t.amount), 
   CASE WHEN d.report_date IS NOT NULL THEN d.report_date ELSE t.billed_date END AS new_date
FROM 
   transaction t LEFT JOIN report_date d ON t.id = d.transaction_id
WHERE new_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30'
```

The Second:

```
SELECT sum(amount) FROM 
 (SELECT t.amount,
    CASE WHEN d.report_date IS NOT NULL THEN d.report_date ELSE t.billed_date END AS date
    FROM transaction t LEFT JOIN report_date d ON t.id = d.transaction_id
 ) t
WHERE t.date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30'
```

**Result:**

The First:

- Unknown column 'new_date' in 'where clause'
- If I replace 'new_date' by 'date': result = 25 (exclude id=1)

The Second:

- result = 30 => Correct, but in my case, when transaction table have about 30k records, the process is too slow.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Sure.  Run an EXPLAIN on your second query and see where one or more additional indexes might be needed.

Comment: In your table description you have `billed_date`. But in your queries you use `t.date`. What is correct?

Comment: Sorry, "billed_date" is correct. I fixed my queries. Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - the part

```
CASE WHEN d.report_date IS NOT NULL THEN d.report_date ELSE t.billed_date END
```

can be written shorter as

```
COALESCE(d.report_date, t.billed_date)
```

or as

```
IFNULL(d.report_date, t.billed_date)
```

In your first query you are using a column alias in the WHERE clause, wich is not allowed. You can fix it by moving the expression behind the alias to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT sum(t.amount)
FROM transaction t LEFT JOIN report_date d ON t.id = d.transaction_id
WHERE COALESCE(d.report_date, t.billed_date) BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30'
```

This is almost the same as your own solution.

Your second query is slow because MySQL has to store the subquery result (30K rows) into a temporary table. Trying to optimize it, you will end up with the same solution above.

However if you have indexes on `transaction.billed_date` and `report_date.report_date` this query still can not use them. In order to use the indexes, you can split the query into two parts:

Entries with a report (will use `report_date.report_date` index):

```
SELECT sum(amount)
FROM transaction t JOIN report_date d ON id = transaction_id 
WHERE d.report_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30'
```

Entries without a report (will use `transaction.billed_date` index):

```
SELECT sum(amount)
FROM transaction t LEFT JOIN report_date d ON id = transaction_id 
WHERE d.report_date IS NULL AND t.billed_dateBETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30'
```

Both queries can use an index. You just need to sum the results, wich can also be done combining the two queries:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT sum(amount)
    FROM transaction t JOIN report_date d ON id = transaction_id 
    WHERE d.report_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30'
) + (
    SELECT sum(amount)
    FROM transaction t LEFT JOIN report_date d ON id = transaction_id 
    WHERE d.report_date IS NULL AND t.billed_dateBETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30'
) AS sum_amount
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally find out the solution with the help from my brother:

```
SELECT sum(amount)
FROM transaction t LEFT JOIN report_date d ON id = transaction_id 
WHERE (report_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30') OR (report_date IS NULL AND billed_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30')
```

Thank you for caring me!

Answer (score 0):

Is fill `table: report_date` with absent values from `table: transaction:` the case?

```
SELECT id FROM report_date WHERE report_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30';

INSERT INTO report_date SELECT id, billed_date FROM transaction WHERE billed_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30' AND id NOT IN (ids_from previous_query);

SELECT sum(t.amount) FROM transaction LEFT JOIN report_date d ON (t.id = d.transaction_id) WHERE d.report_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Second Query is correct,no need to re-write query. But I have one thing to tell you, which will help you a lot when dealing with thousand/millions of records. We have focus on some other things too. Because when your table contains large amount of data(in thousands and millions) of records then it takes time to execute query. It may causes locking also, might be query lock or database gone away kind of issue. To avoid this issue,you just create **INDEX** of one column. Create **INDEX** on that column which act/use on where clauses. Like in your case you can create **INDEX** on **billed_date** column from **transaction** table. Because your result is based on **transaction** table. For more details how to create **index** in mysql/phpmyadmin you can take reference from this http://www.yourwebskills.com/dbphpmyadmintable.php link.

I had been faced same issue at some point of time then I created **INDEX** on column. Now I am dealing with millions of records using mysql.

Comment: In my database, billed_date can not been set as Index column, because there are some records have the same billed date value. Anyway, I understood your idea, and thank you in advanced.

Comment: @Phong Hoang as per my knowledge it's not a big issue  billed_date contains same date value. Because we set index on column it's does not tempered value of that column.  By the Thanks for appreciating me.